# Dúvida em substituir caractere em string assembly (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips

Tenho que fazer um código em **Assembly** mips que solicite uma frase e caso na frase contenha o caractere `-` seja substituído pelo caractere `*`. Até o momento só consegui chegar até esse código:

```
.data
    buffer: .space 256  # Aloca 256 bytes de espaço
    msg1:   .asciiz "Digite uma frase (máximo de 256 caracteres): "
    check:  .asciiz "*"
    result: .asciiz "Você digitou: "

.text
    main: 
        la $a0, msg1    # Carrega no endereço $a0 o conteúdo de msg1 
        li $v0, 4   # Imprimi o conteúdo de msg1
        syscall


        li $v0, 8   # Pega a entrada

        la $a0, buffer   
        li $a1, 256

        move $t0, $a0   # Salva a string digitada em $t0
            syscall

            la $a0, result    # Carrega e mostra "sua resposta" que é uma string
            li $v0, 4   # Imprimi a string  
            syscall

            la $a0, buffer  
            move $a0, $t0   
            li $v0, 4   # Imprimi a string  
            syscall

    end:
        li $v0, 10  # Encerra o programa
        syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que isto seja o que você esta procurando

```
        .data

buffer:     .space 256  # Aloca 256 bytes de espaço

msg1:       .asciiz "Digite uma frase (máximo de 256 caracteres): "
check:      .asciiz "*"
result:     .asciiz "Você digitou: "

        .text
main: 
        la  $a0, msg1    # Carrega no endereço $a0 o conteúdo de msg1 
        li  $v0, 4   # Imprimi o conteúdo de msg1
        syscall

        li  $v0, 8   # Pega a entrada

        la  $a0, buffer   
        li  $a1, 256

        move    $t0, $a0   # Salva a string digitada em $t0
        syscall

        li  $t1,45
        li  $t2,42
altera:
        lb  $a0, ($t0)
        beq $a0,0,termina
        bne $a0,$t1,proximo
        sb  $t2, ($t0)
proximo:
        add $t0,$t0,1
        j   altera
termina:

        la  $a0, result    # Carrega e mostra "sua resposta" que é uma string
        li  $v0, 4   # Imprimi a string  
        syscall

        la  $a0, buffer  
        li  $v0, 4   # Imprimi a string  
        syscall

end:
        li $v0, 10  # Encerra o programa
        syscall
```